# how can I refer dword value at some label? not address of label but value

Tags: syntax, nasm

how can I refer dword value at label?

```
here:
dd 50

times dword [here] db 0
```

there's no such syntax but I wrote for understanding.

I tried to repeat `db 0` for 50 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do that. But you can define an equate for the value 50 and use that in all relevant places:

```
HERE_VALUE equ 50

here:
dd HERE_VALUE

times HERE_VALUE db 0
```

Comment: will you tell me why it is impossible technically?

Comment: I'm not saying that it would be technically impossible for nasm to support this. I'm saying that (as far as I know), nasm doesn't support this _now_.

Comment: in that case... I will choose your answer thank you.